# View using height of match_parent inside LinearLayout with height of wrap_content is breaking the layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view

I'm trying to add a simple horizontal divider (using a View for this) to my layout.

Now the problem is, the View seems to be taking on the height of the ENTIRE layout, rather than just the LinearLayout it is inside of. The LinearLayout it is inside of has a height of wrap_content.

Here is what my layout looks like BEFORE adding these dividers:

[image]

And here is what it looks like AFTER:

[image]

Here is the XML after adding those 2 Views:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Tuesday, March 3, 2014"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/Separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calories_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calories"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calories_today"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2500"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calories_total"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/2750"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calories_percent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="(75%)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/Separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/protein_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Protein"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/protein_today"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="60"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/protein_total"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="/80"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/protein_percent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="(75%)"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>        

        <View
            android:id="@+id/Separator"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carbs_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Carbs"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carbs_today"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="250"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carbs_total"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="/300"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carbs_percent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="(75%)"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/Separator"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fat_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fat"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fat_today"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="50"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fat_total"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="/80"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fat_percent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="(75%)"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: No offence but that layout is far too complex to spend time making sense of it. Bearing in mind each section (Calories, Protein, Carbs and Fat) have identical requirements, I'd create a single generic layout with label, today, total and percent TextViews and then use <merge> to simplify things. Sorry that doesn't answer your question but you'd probably be doing yourself a favour if you did it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 layouts in the lower row must have

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```